# How to find linked_server name in sql server management studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to query the following in sql server management studio:

```
select colname from openquery (linked_server, 'exec XX.YY.PrcName @Parameter')
```

When i try to give **XX** as linked server name i am getting an error.
Is that right or how do i find the linked_server name ?

Answer (score 3):

To check linked server name :

```
select * from sys.sysservers
```

you can easily run any procedure in another server through linked server as:

```
exec <procedure name><parameneters> at <linked server name>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of linked servers use:

```
EXEC SP_LINKEDSERVERS
```

If you want to SELECT something from Linked server:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [SOMESERVER\SOMEINSTANCE].somedatabase.dbo.sometable;
```

To EXECUTE something on linked server:

```
EXEC [SOMESERVER\SOMEINSTANCE].somedatabase.dbo.somestoredprocedure

SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([SOMESERVER\SOMEINSTANCE].somedatabase.dbo.somestoredprocedure)
```

More info:

- [sqlauthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/06/sql-server-executing-remote-stored-procedure-calling-stored-procedure-on-linked-server/)
- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: My pleasure! If any of the answers helps you, feel free to upvote/accept them!

Answer (score 0):

You also can use [sys.servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178530.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Select * From SYS.SERVERS
```

> When server_id = 0, this is the server name.
>   When server_id >0 , this is the local name of linked server.